# Getting MQJCA1025 Error while starting MQ Listener

Tags: java, jboss, jms, ibm-mq, mq

Getting MQJCA1025 error while starting up the Asynchronous Listener/reader on IBM-MQ as -

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: MQJCA1025: The
>   message consumer must not have a message listener. An application
>   attempted to set a message listener for a JMS message consumer. This
>   exception occurs only if the application is running in a managed
>   environment. Modify the application so that it does use a message
>   listener.

Below is the init method where listener setup is done -

```
  public void init(){
              ConnectionFactory qConnectionFactory = null;
              Connection connection = null;
              try{
                     Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                     qConnectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/Connection");
                     Destination receiverQueue = null;
                     if(null != qConnectionFactory){
                           connection = qConnectionFactory.createConnection();
                           if(null !=connection){
                                  receiverQueue = (Destination) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/RESPONSE");
                                  if(null != receiverQueue){
                                         Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                                         if(null != session){            
                                                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(receiverQueue);
                                                consumer.setMessageListener(this);
                                                connection.start();
                                         }
                                  }
                           }
                     }
              }
              catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
              }
       }
```

IBM resolution at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610734 doesn't mentions the fix to be made at listener/client side

Answer (score 1):

MQJCA1025 error message says don't do the following:

```
consumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

The link you give is very clear:

***Cause***

*Calling setMessageListener() method in a managed environment is a violation of J2EE specification, and therefore should not be used.*

***Resolving the problem***

*Your JMS application needs to be altered to not call setMessageListener() method. **Instead, Activation Specifications are provided for the functionality which this method provides***

Comment: Roger, can you please provide examples for alternates of setMessageListener

Answer (score 0):

In other words, your Application Server does the hookup for you :-) Your fix would be to NOT set the listener yourself, but instead make sure you implement a MessageDrivenBean and the application server will do the registration for you. You only need to implement onMessage(). See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JMS_Examples-A_Point_To_Point_With_MDB_Example.html) for an example with JBoss.